# VueJS - unknown local action type: addProductToCart, global type: cart/addProductToCart

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am pretty new to VueJS so, please, go easy on me. I am trying to implement a shopping cart using VueJS. I have a button 'Add to Cart' with a click handler called `addProductToCart(product)` which should add the product to the cart and when I click the button I get an error `unknown local action type: addProductToCart, global type: cart/addProductToCart`. I am stuck, I don't know what I might be doing wrong.

## Component.vue

```
<button @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to Cart</button>

<script>
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
      computed: {
        //...
      },
      methods: mapActions('cart', [
        'addProductToCart'
      ])
    }
</script>
```

## store/modules/cart.js

```
import * as types from '../types';

const state = {
  items: []
};

const getters = {
  cartProducts: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    return state.items.map(({ name, quantity }) => {
      const product = rootState.products.all.find(product => product.name === name)
      return {
        name: product.name,
        price: product.price,
        quantity
      }
    })
  },
  cartTotalPrice: (state, getters) => {
    return getters.cartProducts.reduce((total, product) => {
      return total + product.price * product.quantity
    }, 0)
  }
};

const mutations = {
  [types.PUSH_PRODUCT_TO_CART] (state, { product_name }) {
    state.items.push({
      product_name,
      quantity: 1
    })
  }
};

const actions = {
  [types.ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART] ({ state, commit }, product) {
    commit(types.PUSH_PRODUCT_TO_CART, { name: product.name })
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

## types.js

```
export const ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART = 'cart/ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART'
export const PUSH_PRODUCT_TO_CART = 'cart/PUSH_PRODUCT_TO_CART'
```

I am using namespaced modules because I have products state and cart state and would like to have separate actions, mutations, etc. for each.

Comment: is your result same when you change `namespaced: false` ?

Comment: No, it then says `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions(): cart/`

Comment: Where are your mutations?

Comment: @StevenB. I've updated my `cart.js` with mutations as well as getters.

Comment: The action has an incorrect signature. It should be `addProductToCart` not `[types.ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART]`

Comment: You are a genius :) Write an answer and I'll upvote it and accept it because you helped me solve my problem:) Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your action has an incorrect signature of `[types.ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART]`.

It should be:

```js
const actions = {
  addProductToCart ({ state, commit }, product) {
    commit(types.PUSH_PRODUCT_TO_CART, { name: product.name })
  }
};
```